# How to prove divergent sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For this question, I know that the sequence diverges to infinity, but I'm not sure if I am doing it right. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the following sequence is convergent or divergent

$a_n = \{8n^3 + n^2 -2\}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$

Wts for any $M>0$, there exists some $N>0$, st if $n>N$, then $a_n>M$.

$n^3 > N^3 > M$

$n^3(8 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n^3}) > N^3(8 + \frac{1}{N} - \frac{2}{N^3}) > M$

$n^3(8 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n^3}) > N > (\frac{M}{8+\frac{1}{N} -\frac{2}{N^3}})^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: $8n^3+n^2-2>n^3>N^3$ If  you take $N=\sqrt[3]M$ then from the transitivity $8n^3+n^2-2>N^3=M$

Comment: If $n>N$ then $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}$ for $n,N$ positive. Similarly $\frac{1}{N^3}$. This argument doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M > 0$.

For any $n \ge \sqrt[3]{M+2}$ we have

$$8n^3 + n^2 - 2 \ge n^3 - 2 \ge (M+2) - 2 = M$$

Hence your sequence is unbounded.

Comment: Why did you drop the $8n^3$?

Comment: @dg123 I just used that $8n^3 \ge n^3$ and $n^2 \ge 0$ to make things more simple.

Comment: Do you mean $\ge n^2 -2$?

Comment: @dg123 Nope, but this also works:
$$\underbrace{8n^3}_{\ge 0} + n^2 - 2 \ge n^2 - 2 \ge (M+2)-2 = M$$
when you take $n \ge \sqrt{M+2}$.

Comment: You mean capital n = root m plus 2?

Comment: @dg123 Yes, if we set $N = \lceil \sqrt{M+2}\rceil$, then for all $n \ge N$ we get $8n^3 + n^2 - 2 \ge M$.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant to understand, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We fix $M>2$ and we look for $N$ such that $\forall n>N$

$$a_n = 8n^3 + n^2 -2>M$$

then choose $n=M$ and check that

$$8M^3 + M^2 -2>M\iff 8M^3 + M^2>M+2$$

which is true.

Then it suffice to choose $N\ge M$.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: Observe that your sequence is strictly increasing and integer-valued. Thus $a_{n}\geq a_{n-1}+1$, and so $a_n\geq a_0+n$. Now you should be able to easily prove $a_n$ is unbounded and hence divergent.

Comment: Isn't it much easier to prove by definition?

Comment: @dg123 There are lots of ways to prove that your sequence is divergent. All of them (at least the reasonably ones one could think of) are easy. I just offered an approach that I thought you or future readers could find relatively simple.

Comment: Don't we need to use induction for this one?

Comment: @dg123 Certainly one can use induction to prove that $a_n\geq a_{n-1}+1$ implies $a_n\geq a_0+n$, but I don't know if one can strictly justify this statement on a logic level without induction. Honestly, I don't label statements like this as using induction in my head, but I don't care much about those logic aspects so...